# connect Mysql server with windows mobile 6

Tags: mysql, windows, c#-3.0, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6

i am developing a application for windows mobile 6 device. i want to update its database with Mysql server database but unfortunately this device have not any network connection facility. so i have to connect this device with PC to update the database.. process is when i click "SYNC" button data should transfer between the server and local DB so help me to do this ..
any  link or codes or anything that help me to do this work thank you..
this is my device http://www.posguys.com/mobile-computers_6/Motorola-MC3100_1124/

Answer (score 0):

although you dont have a 'network' connection you can use ActiveSync/WindowsMobileDeviceCenter to connet the mc3100 to your PCs network using the passthru connection of ActiveSync.

So, first step is to download the MySql Connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads and then add a reference to it in your .NET Compact Framework/SmartDevice project. Or are you using a different programming environment?

Nect step is to try a connection to your MySql server. If you succeed, nect step is to follow the MySql data sync programming.